# Is it possible to save a modified PDF using MuPDF?

Tags: mupdf

I have edited a PDF using some of MuPDFs modification API and I cannot figure out how to save this modified PDF to disk. Is this possible? If so how can I save this PDF?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to call pdf_write_document. However this was added after the release of version 1.0 so you need to get the latest source code from the Git repository if you want to use it.

I'm told there is code in mupdfclean.c that demonstrates the use of the function.